# Wobbling in matplotlib animation

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

This is my first post, so I apologise if I am doing something wrong.  I couldn't find any similar questions.
I am trying to generate an animation/video using matplotlib. The animation shows a dot moving along a curve.  In my attempt to do this, I can see the point wobbling as it moves along the curve. How can I get rid of this effect?  Here's a short script able to reproduce the effect and a gif animation.  Thanks in advance

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N=800#The bigger this number the worse the effect
s=np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,N)
xy=np.array([s,np.power(s,0.8)])#

plt.ion()

fig, ax=plt.subplots()
line1,=ax.plot(xy[0,:],xy[1,:],'-g')
t=0
ms=8
line2,=ax.plot(xy[0,t],xy[1,t],'or',markersize=ms)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
disc=1
M=N#int(N/2)
for lab in range(0,M,disc):

    line1.set_xdata(xy[0,:])
    line1.set_ydata(xy[1,:])
    line2.set_xdata(xy[0,lab])
    line2.set_ydata(xy[1,lab])
    fig.canvas.draw()
    fig.canvas.flush_events()

print("done!")
```

[image]